# Putting a middle host between two firewall devices

Tags: ipsec

Here is the network topology that I have:

Private network 1 --> IPFire Firewall 1 <---> IPFire Firewall 2 <-- Private network 2

I can ping from private network 1 to private network 2, that is after creating an IPsec tunnel between the two IPFire devices.

What I want to do is to have a middle device between the two IPFire devices, the network topology is like this:

Private network 1 --> IPFire Firewall 1 <-- middle device --> IPFire Firewall 2 <-- Private network 2

I want to use this middle device as a packet sniffer for the packets flawing between IPFire 1 and 2. What I don't know is how transfer the connection from one interface of the middle device to the second, the IPsec tunnel uses private IPs, so I don't know who the middle device will affect the tunnel establishment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To easily see the traffic in it's encrypted state between the two firewalls which you own and manage.  I suggest a hub.  It requires no configuration, you simply plug in both firewall's outside interfaces and then plug in your laptop with monitoring tools (may need to adjust NIC settings/promiscuous etc) to see all the traffic flowing between the two devices.

Comment: 1. The middle device could be a laptop or one-board computer on which a Linux distribution is installed, although, I didn't figure out how to install the OS on the one-board computer I have, I have An ALIX board series 6 board. In the case of the laptop we will have to use the switch, right? 2. I want to see all the types of packets flawing between the IPsec devices.

Comment: In this case then you won't be able to from the 'middle', but just as good, you can set your device up just off the inside interface of your firewalls and get the same effect.  If your firewalls support SPAN and you have enough ports for it you can mirror that way, otherwise as user5469 said you could introduce a switch or a tap right on the inside of the firewall to mirror/SPAN to your laptop.

Comment: As we continue to clarify I'll edit my actual answer so it's helpful/relevant/clear for future viewers.

Comment: The switch seems to be a good solution, I think. The topology is like net1>>IPFire1>>Switch>>IPFire2>>net2. I will connect the laptop to the switch, right? I don't actually know how to do port mirroring. And I really would like to apply this solution on virtualbox first! I don't know how to simulate a switch?

Comment: What you're listing here won't work, because (at least in your first post) - the two networks have an IPsec tunnel between them.  So doing it the way you propose you'll get packets, but they'll all be encrypted and you won't be able to glean anything from your captures.

Comment: You'll have to do something like this: net1>>switch(with laptop)>>firewall>><<firewall<<net2 - and this again is assuming a lot, like your firewalls don't support SPAN natively (if they do you don't need a switch).  If you're looking to do this on the cheap you can always forgoe the switch and learning about SPAN and just use a hub.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to see the packets unencrypted. In the network I have now I installed and ran tcpdump on IPFire2 while pinging from IPFire 1 or it's private network, what I saw was IPsec ESP packets. I want to see the same thing put from the outside of the tunnel. I hope I haven't mislead you until now.

Comment: No worries!  So you want to see the IPsec packets between the two in their encrypted state?  After looking into IPFire, if it's just a linux box, you should be able to (with tcpdump) see both ingoing/outgoing packets on whatever interface you're listening on which should net you what you want.  Maybe I'm still misunderstanding you?

Comment: Also point of preference, try tcpick w/ -C if you want to see stuff moving in real time (like watching the tunnel build etc).

Comment: I have already installed and ran tcpdump on IPFire and I can see the packets. Put I want to see it from a device this is not part of the tunnel. Will the switch in the middle with port mirroring allow it?

Comment: Ok, cool we're on the same page.  Little bit more followup:  WHY do you want to see this (may help answer or give a different solution)?  Do you own the space between the two firewalls (like, can you disconnect it or is it a production pipe, a network you don't own etc).

Comment: It is just the professor's request, this is part of a graduation project :) I own the space between the two firewalls, this are just two networks connected with a cable.

Comment: My personal opinion is just grab an oldschool hub, super cheap and the fastest/easiest way to setup monitoring between two segments.  Just plug firewall 1 and 2 into it and then your laptop into a separate port and voila, you can see everything going between them with no config.  You can find one cheaper than a true network tap as well.

Comment: I updated my answer to be clear and to the point for future readers, please mark as answer if this works for you!

Comment: I need to check that this works as you said, I don't have the hardware right now, can I simulate a hup on VirtualBox?

Comment: I have no clue if you can or not, if you're on a campus I have to image they have a lab and some old dusty hubs lying around for posterity.  Otherwise unless your laptop has two NIC's don't see how you'd work that out anyway even if your could emulate a hub (which GNS3 can do and actually take and forward real traffic).

Comment: Oh, I will connect the laptop to the hup, since the hup is flooding incoming packets, the encrypted packets will be seen by the laptop, right?

Comment: Correct, it'll see everything from everything plugged into it, with no additional config done by you !  If you validate this please mark as answer :)

Comment: Don't worry I won't forget to mark it. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this exactly, but my understanding is that you would want some sort of physical splitter in between to capture traffic to a 3rd (middle) device.  Would depend on the type of physical layer1 connection.  See link for an example of network tap solutions
http://www.flukenetworks.com/enterprise-network/network-monitoring/Tap-Solutions

Answer (score 0):

You could also put a switch in the middle and connect the sniffer to a mirror port. This will add another device to your setup but no special configuration will be needed on the sniffer.

Comment: Your suggestion seems promising, however I don't know much about how to configure this mirror port and how to connect it to the sniffer.

Comment: Basically you will have to connect the two firewalls to the switch on the same VLAN. Then connect the sniffer to another port and configure it as a mirror. The exact commands ton configure a mirror port depends on the switch model. In cisco it will look like:
Switch# configure terminal
Switch# monitor session 1 source interface fastethernet 0/1
Switch# monitor session 1 destination interface fastethernet 0/3